# Get build requestor using Groovy script (Jenkins / email-ext)

Tags: groovy, jenkins, email-ext

I want to get the username and/or email address of the build requestor in a post-build script.

*Sidenote: I want the requestor so I can set the email sender of the post-build email notification dynamically in the email-ext plugin's pre-send script.*

[`AbstractBuild`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html) has built-in support for `AbstractBuild.getCulprits()` and `AbstractBuild.hasParticipant(User user)` but I can't find a method for retrieving the requestor. I can't find any useful reference in [reference list](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/class-use/User.html) to the `User` class either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve it via the `Cause` of the the build, as [recommended in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902426/in-jenkins-how-do-builds-know-who-requested-them).

The reason that the build requestor can be found in the cause for a build makes perfect sense when you think about it: Not every build is directly triggered by a user.
If it is triggered by a user, the list of causes for the build contains a `Cause.UserIdCause`, with the user's id and name.

This code snippet worked for me. It extracts the username from the build via the cause and sets the From and ReplyTo headers. I use it in the pre-send script of the [email-ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) Jenkins plugin.

```
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress

cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class);
username = cause.getUserName()
id = cause.getUserId()
email = new InternetAddress(String.format("%s <%s@example.com>", username, id))

msg.setFrom(email)
msg.setReplyTo(email);
```

Comment: Thanks for the script!  Note, I use the following built-in Jenkins API method to get the email:
`hudson.model.User user = hudson.model.User.get(cause.getUserId);`
`email = user.getProperty(hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty).getAddress() ;`

Answer (score 0):

To simply **send a mail to build requestor** (i.e. what you state in your sidenote to be your actual goal/problem), you can use the emailext step with `requestor()` in `recipientProviders` in the pipeline.

Example from [email-ext plugin documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/email-ext-2.99/README.adoc#pipeline-step):

```
emailext body: 'Test Message',
    recipientProviders: [developers(), requestor()],
    subject: 'Test Subject',
    to: 'test@example.com'
```

(This feature was added after the question was posted: [changelog](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/485fb0f9657c50f4499650716e4b414670ed72b1/CHANGELOG.adoc#244-june-13-2016))