# Jenkinsfile - Jenkins build user getUserName() NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getUserName() on null object Mutli Branch Indexing Scanning

Tags: jenkins, nullpointerexception, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline

Jenkins **2.138.1.2-rolling** --and-- using **[MultiBranch Pipeline](https://devopscube.com/jenkins-multibranch-pipeline-tutorial/)** (to build build from master, branches and Pull Requests etc).

I want to show Jenkins build job's user who initiated the build in build description.

Ex:
[image]

For implemennting the same, in my *`Jenkinsfile`*, I have the following code at the top:

```
@NonCPS
def getBuildUser() {
    def build = currentBuild.rawBuild
    def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class)
    def BUILD_USER = cause.getUserName()
    
    return BUILD_USER
}

pipeline {
    ...
}
```

Class definition: https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.UserIdCause.html shows the method is **NOT Deprecated** (like it's in the case of [UserCause](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Cause.UserCause.html) class).

In Jenkinsfile, under the stages section, I have the following code, which is implementing this successfully.

```
stages {
   stage ('Start') {
       steps {
           script {
                   // Set Build Description
                   def BUILD_USER= getBuildUser()
                   currentBuild.description = "${BUILD_USER}: ${RELEASE_TAG} => ${DOCKER_IMAGES}"
           }

           sh '''
                 set +x
                 echo -e "\n\n-- Starting build process.\n"
              '''
       }
   }
   .. more stages are here ..
 }
```

As I'm using Multi-Branch Pipeline job, I see all the branches/PR including master and on the side bar, I see the following links:

[image]

The setting for multi-branch **scan period** is set for every `10` minutes.
[image]

I'm seeing that sometimes the **build is FAILING** with the following error i.e. `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getUserName() on null object` and other times, the build is successful all the way and build description is also good.

```
[Bitbucket] Build result notified
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getUserName() on null object
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedCall$1.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at WorkflowScript.getBuildUser(WorkflowScript:5)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:158)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:156)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:125)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:130)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:75)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor333.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:347)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:259)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:247)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I noticed, that this is happening **ONLY** when `Multi-Branch Scanning` / `Branch Indexing` is running in the background because, as all the failed builds have the following getting listed in that build number's console page.
[image]

For successful builds with build description and all, the above "**BRANCH INDEXING**" box is not visible (against that successful build #).

**Why I'm getting this** `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getUserName() on null object` error (when Scanning is in progress in the background) --or **what can I do to avoid the build failure**?

**PS**: To recreate this issue, a user can simply just click on the
sidebar icon/link for ***Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now*** which will result in a failed build and console output showing:

[image]

**PS**: Installing a new plugin will probably require some time(1-2 weeks)/scanning/approval process from Security team, so not an option I think, at least until that approval happens. Ex: https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-user-vars-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid build failure, for now, I enabled `try` and `catch` and setting value for BUILD_USER if `getCause(...)` is going to fail ... as when someone clicks on the side-bar link `Scan MultiBranch Pipeline Now`, then console output or Jenkins **doesn't set a USER who clicked** on that **side-bar link** to launch the build (if there are any changes to be built) and shows `Branch Indexing` as first line in output (instead of showing: `Started by user <some name> (someUserID)`).

Thus, the following will set BUILD_USER to a meaningful value and won't FAIL the build.

```
@NonCPS
def getBuildUser() {
        def build = currentBuild.rawBuild
        def BUILD_USER = "ToBeSet"

        try {
             def cause = build.getCause(hudson.model.Cause.UserIdCause.class)
             BUILD_USER = cause.getUserName()
        } catch(Exception ex) {
             println "\n\n-- Build caused by either Multi-Branch Pipeline Scanning -or- Timer i.e. not directly by a logged in user\n";
             BUILD_USER = "Multi_Branch_Scan_or_Timer"
        }

        return BUILD_USER
}
```

I'll still like to know if there's a way, we can find, who clicked on the side-bar link (logged in user), will poke into it.